# Lettrine character messes with paragraph setting

Tags: memoir, tcolorbox, paragraphs, lettrine

The code below

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\setlength{\textwidth}{0.8\paperwidth}
\setlength{\textheight}{0.8\paperheight}
\setlength{\uppermargin}{3cm}

\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout


%\usepackage{lettrine}
%\newfontfamily\zallman[Scale=3]{ZallmanCaps}
%\renewcommand*{\LettrineFont}{\zallman}
%\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\tcolorboxenvironment{thm}{
    breakable,
    colback=red!10,
    boxrule=0pt,
    left=3pt,right=3pt,top=3pt,bottom=3pt,
    oversize=0pt,
    sharp corners
}

\begin{document}
    %\lettrine[lines = 2, lraise=-0.05]{S}{ome} 
    Some text is here which is extremely long such that it spans two lines of this page solely for the purpose of filling two lines. 
    \begin{thm}
        If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then it holds that
        \[
        \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f\Bigl(a+k\cdot\frac{b-a}{n}\Bigr)
        =\int_a^b f(x)\,dx
        \]
    \end{thm}
    \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

correctly yields
[image]

But adding a lettrine character messes with the paragraph formation right after the paragraph including that character:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\setlength{\textwidth}{0.8\paperwidth}
\setlength{\textheight}{0.8\paperheight}
\setlength{\uppermargin}{3cm}

\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout


\usepackage{lettrine}
\newfontfamily\zallman[Scale=3]{ZallmanCaps}
\renewcommand*{\LettrineFont}{\zallman}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\tcolorboxenvironment{thm}{
    breakable,
    colback=red!10,
    boxrule=0pt,
    left=3pt,right=3pt,top=3pt,bottom=3pt,
    oversize=0pt,
    sharp corners
}

\begin{document}
    \lettrine[lines = 2, lraise=-0.05]{S}{ome} text is here which is extremely long such that it spans two lines of this page solely for the purpose of filling two lines. 
    \begin{thm}
        If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then it holds that
        \[
        \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f\Bigl(a+k\cdot\frac{b-a}{n}\Bigr)
        =\int_a^b f(x)\,dx
        \]
    \end{thm}
    \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Where does this issue come from and how to fix it?

---

**Edit**:

Ulrike Fischer suggested to add `\parshape=0` after `end{thm}`, but, as the screenshot below exhibits, both the color box and the next paragraph are still spuriously indented.

[image]

Comment: your document can't be tested as you use a local font. But try with `\parshape=0` after `\end{thm}`. See the documentation of lettrine for an explication.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Please check the edit. (ZallmanCaps is freely available here: https://www.dafont.com/zallman-caps.font)

Comment: try with \noindent. And I will certainly not spent my time to download and install some font. It shouldn't be too hard for you to make an example without it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: `\noindent` does not change the result of the edit.

Comment: Use `\par` or empty line just before `\begin{thm}`

Comment: @wipet: That saved the day! If you supply an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: as wipet said, but please could you really not demonstrate the issue using a generably usable document? `! Package fontspec Error: The font "ZallmanCaps" cannot be found.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Honestly, I am not fluent in using `lettrine` package with any font, as it does yield weird results with many of them. Moreover, if you note, there are many questions (like: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235748/accented-character-in-ornamental-drop-caps-using-zallman-caps) here in which this font is an essential part, and contributors to those questions had not considered the `MWE`s of those questions unusable.

Comment: You could easily have tried with the default font or if you found it needed  that font, you should have specified that, with a link, in the question rather than letting people find out after they have copied your example locally and get unexpected unrelated errors to fix before addressing the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: First of all, in the previous questions to which I referred (just like the cited one above), OP supplied no link to the font. Second, even if I had done it, your logic would be the same as Ulrike Fischer's (" I will certainly not spent my time to download and install some font.")

Comment: @User no: I would have removed the font call and tested without, as  I did anyway as you see below, it would just have saved everyone helping one iteration through an error loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your example can be simplified to

```
\documentclass{memoir}


\usepackage{lettrine}

\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}


\begin{document}
    \lettrine[lines = 2, lraise=-0.05]{S}{ome} text is here which
 is extremely long such that it spans two lines of this page
 solely for the purpose of filling two lines.{

some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text 

}
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Lettrine sets a special paragraph shape which is reverted at the end of the paragraph, but if that is in a group the resetting is lost, so the shape leaks to later paragraphs.

End the paragraph before starting the group. (`{` here, `\begin{thm}` in the orginal)

```
\documentclass{memoir}


\usepackage{lettrine}

\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}


\begin{document}
    \lettrine[lines = 2, lraise=-0.05]{S}{ome} text is here which
 is extremely long such that it spans two lines of this page
 solely for the purpose of filling two lines.

{

some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text 

}
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\end{document}
```

[image]