# How to use a custom font from LuaLaTeX with coloredlettrine?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, lettrine

I have installed a new custom font (OTF & TTF); and I would like to use it with the package *coloredlettrine*.

Which steps would I need to follow to be able to use it?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{coloredlettrine}
\renewcommand{\EBLettrineBackColor}{blue}

\begin{document}
    \coloredlettrine{P}{ray}:
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235760 for an example of using the technique with a font other than EB Garamond.

Comment: Also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277331

Comment: @Thérèse, thank you so much!