# Zallman drop caps

Tags: drop-cap, fancy

I would like to use this (https://physica.dev/posts/2021/06/fancy-drop-caps-Latex.html) but I don't understand what I have to do in my code to use it (in the text itself). Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Have a look here, too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=zallman , e.g. at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235748/accented-character-in-ornamental-drop-caps-using-zallman-caps .

Comment: Thank you that's also interesting !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested code is uselessly complicated. You don't need a `.sty` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\input{Zallman.fd}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{Maroon}\usefont{U}{Zallman}{xl}{n}}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{L}{iquid} scintillation \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I needed !!!

Comment: @TexDuinoCpp You don't need a package but, if you want one the code you linked to is just a copy of the package you doubtless already have. So you can just say `\usepackage{Zallman}` and then `\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{Maroon}\Zallmanfamily}`. I was asked to provide the package(s) though I forget who by.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a package but, if you want one the linked code is just a copy of a package provided by your TeX distribution. So you can just say `\usepackage{Zallman}` and then `\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{Maroon}\Zallmanfamily}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{Zallman}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for philosophical mock text

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{Maroon}\Zallmanfamily}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{K}{ant} \kant[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: dropped cap with Zallman initials]

I was asked to provide the package(s) in `cfr-initials` though I forget who by.

Comment: Thank you for your help !!

Comment: Still 2 of reputation to get and I can vote up your answer ;)

Comment: @TexDuinoCpp to increase rep to +100 read this -- https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations